# Get link to nested object by string key

Tags: javascript

For example, I have an object:

```
var model = {user:{name: 'Mike', phones:{mobile: '00000'}}};
```

and a string key:

```
var string_key = 'user.phones.mobile';
```

I can parse it to get the array key:

```
var keys = string_key.split('.');
```

How can I can get link to object phones from `model`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: I write it http://jsfiddle.net/yvb5a8y6/ with updating last key data

Answer (score -1):

By doing this:

```
model[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]];
```

This seems a bit strange though..

Comment: I don't know amount of keys